# Python 3.5 gzip sometimes crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

So I have a situation where Python will crash while unzipping files. It's inconsistent. Sometimes it'll get thru 2 files and other times it'll get thru 5. Very random.

OS: Windows 7
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48)
[MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
File size: range between 10MB - 100MB
Any help is appreciated. Here's the code I'm running

```
def main():
  iterate_files()
  print('Completed successfully!')

def iterate_files():
  fl = [f for f in listdir(gz_source_folder) if isfile(join(gz_source_folder, f))]

  for f in fl:
    print('current file: {0}'.format(f))
    unzip_file(join(gz_source_folder, f))

def unzip_file(gz_source_file):
  print("unzipping...")
  gz_base_name = os.path.basename(gz_source_file)
  csv_file_base_name = os.path.splitext(gz_base_name)
  csv_target_file = join(unzip_target, csv_file_base_name[0])
  with gzip.open(gz_source_file, 'rb') as gz_file, open(csv_target_file, 'wb') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(gz_file.read()) # sometimes crashes here
  csv_file.close()
  gz_file.close()
```

Here is the stack:

```
unzipping...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 2364, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1784, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "C:\sandbox\development\python\util_scripts\func_test\extract.py", line 61, in <module>
main()
  File "C:\sandbox\development\python\util_scripts\func_test\extract.py", line 57, in main
iterate_files()
  File "C:\sandbox\development\python\util_scripts\func_test\extract.py", line 27, in iterate_files
unzip_file(join(gz_source_folder, f))
  File "C:\sandbox\development\python\util_scripts\func_test\extract.py", line 35, in unzip_file
csv_file.write(gz_file.read())
  File "C:\python\lib\gzip.py", line 274, in read
return self._buffer.read(size)
MemoryError
```

Comment: _Sometimes it'll get thru 2 files and other times it'll get thru 5. Very random._  Does it behave randomly on the same set of files?

Comment: The error seems to be caused by a lack of memory on your PC.  The randomness can be due to memory being consumed by various other programs that are open.

Comment: John, yep! Same exact set of files.

Comment: As far as the memory, I have over 50% available while running this process. I'm not sure how it can run out.

Comment: Have you looked at a memory usage graph?  Maybe the process is asking for a huge chunk of memory (greater than 50% system ram)?

Comment: Yes, I have taken a look at the memory usage graph. I don't see any spikes or any other anomalies. What's weird is that I can process 2 files successfully and it'll crash during the 3rd file. If I isolate the 3rd file and only process that one it goes thru successfully. When I start processing files again it'll process 3 files and crash on the 4th. I repeat and it crashed on file number 3 again. I can remove the 3rd file and it'll get thru 7 or 8 files until it crashes again. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe try calling `del` on the file objects at the end of `unzip_file()`?

Comment: Also, a minor point: you don't need the `close()` calls at the end of `unzip_file()`.  The files are closed automatically because you used a context manager to open them.

Comment: Adding the close() was just an added measure to try to resolve the problem. I'll try the delete to see if that helps. Thanks for your help.